# Consider the polynomial $p(x)=x^{2021}-x+1$, calculate the sum

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$
r_{1}^{2021}+r_{2}^{2021}+\ldots+r_{n}^{2021}
$$

where $r_i$ are the 2021 roots of $p$

I'm not sure how to start, I know that can be done with Moivre's formula but I don't get any result.

Answer (score 6):

If $r$ is a root, then $r^{2021}-r+1=0$, so $r^{2021}=r-1$.  We can therefore rewrite your sum as $\sum (r_i-1)$.  Since the coefficient of $x^{2020}$ in $p(x)$ is $0$, $\sum r_i=0$.  Therefore, we have $$\sum r_i^{2021} =\sum r_i-1=\sum r_i -\sum 1 = 0-2021=-2021.$$

Answer (score 1):

If $a$ is a root of $x^n-x+1=0, a^n=a-1=y$(say)

$$\implies(y+1)^n-y=0\implies y^n+ny^{n-1}+\cdots+1=0$$

$$\implies\sum_{k=1}^nr_k=-\dfrac n1$$